# Copying files from folders in one directory to a common folder

Tags: shell, unix, sh, ksh

I am writing a script to copy files from folders under one directory to a common location. For this I need to iterate over the folders in the directory. The folders are datewise so I am using less than and greater than. But I am not able to get into the loop. Can you please let me know what is wrong with my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

SCRIPT_DIRECTORY='/abc/script'
DATA_DIRECTORY='/a/inbox'
TARGET_DIRECTORY='/abc/final'
START_DATE=$2
END_DATE=$3

if [ $1 == 'a' ]
then
   while [[ $2 -gt 20151201 ]] && [[ $3 -lt 20151231 ]]
   do
     for file in `ls $DATA_DIRECTORY`
     do
        cp name* $TARGET_DIRECTORY
     done
  done
fi
```

Here the folders under a/inbox directory are made datewise starting from 20151201 till 20151231. So I need to fetch all the files starting from name to a common target directory
I am also trying to make it as a script where if I pass parameters like a,b,c it will go to the respective data directory and fetches the files from there

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` statement is wrong. Write it like this:

```
while (($2 > 20151201 && $3 < 20151231))
```

Please also verify, that $1, $2 and $3 indeed contain the values which you expect.

Comment: This is resulting in syntax error

line 13: ((: > 20151201 &&  < 20151231: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "> 20151201 &&  < 20151231")

Comment: Either you forgot to type the parameters, or the parameters are empty. You can verify it by using `while (( ${2:?two} > 20151201 && ${3:?three} < 20151231))` .

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I have tried it and it works)

`if [ $1 == 'a' ]
then
     # use ls $DATA_DIRECTORY as mentioned by you; i could not bring it here
     for file in`ls $DATA_DIRECTORY
     `do
        if [ $file -ge 20151201 -a $file -le 20151231 ]; then
           cp $DATA_DIRECTORY/$file/* $TARGET_DIRECTORY
        fi
     done
fi`

You need only one loop for iteration and have moved the date check (if condition) inside the loop. I have use `-ge` instead of `-gt` as it looks like somekind of monthy data. Maybe you can adjust to your need. Hope it helps.

Comment: any idea how can i increment the date in the loop. the date format should be yyyymmdd

Comment: the question is not clear to me. May I know the usecase

Comment: I have a date in format of 20151201, how can I increment the date to 20151202

Comment: "count=`expr $count + 1`" where count is a variable. Place the forward slash before `expr` and after `1`. Did the earlier solution worked for you?